# Given two IID N(0,1) variables X and Y, what's $P(X+2Y \geq 0 | X \geq 0)$?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

My attempt is that
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X+2Y  \geq 0 \mid X \geq 0) &= P(Y \geq 0) + P(Y\leq0 \text{ and }|Y| < X/2 \mid X \geq 0)\\
&= 1/2 + P(-X/2 <Y < 0 \mid X \geq 0)\\
&= 1/2 + \int_0^\inf (\int_{-x/2}^0 f_y(y)dy) f_x(x)dx
\end{aligned}
$$

Which doesn't seem easy to evaluate. Is my thought process correct up to this point or am I completely off the track? How should I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed is irrelevant; all that matters is that they are IID symmetric random variables with mean $0$.

Another way to put it is this:  What is the fraction of the region in the right half-plane that also satisfies the inequality $X + 2Y \ge 0$?

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Though I thought the joint distribution being circular symmetric is a special property of bivariate normal? Are you saying this is true for any pair of IID symmetric random variables with mean 0?

Comment: @wwyws Yes.  For example, suppose $X$ and $Y$ are IID uniform on $[-1,1]$.  Your answer would be the same; in fact, it would be very easy to compute explicitly.